# unable to remove text entry from systray

Tags: ibus, input-method

I am using Ubuntu 14 and I have created a custom ibus m17n(.mim file) input source and everything was working fine. But now I am unable to delete it ( it doesn't show up in Text Entry settings), however I manually removed it from (/usr/share/m17n). It still shows up in the systray. How do I remove it?

Comment: Have you tried to log out and log in again?

Comment: yes, many times

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe you should try to purge ibus-m17n and relogin (or maybe reboot).